# How to disable powerline symbols?

Tags: powerline, vim-powerline

I use powerline installed with `pip install powerline-status`.

Is there a way to just disable fancy symbols, so I do not have to configure any font to make it work, whatever environment and segments I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a ascii only theme provided by default.

To activate it, set the following code in `.config/powerline/config.json`.

```
{
    "common": {
        "default_top_theme": "ascii"
    },
}
```

Comment: took three days to find this.